# Can I change the difficulty of Metro 2033?

Tags: metro-2033

I started my Game at easy and after 12 hours of playing i decided it´s too boring and too easy. May I change the difficulty with some Tools without influencing my savegame stats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found out that you easily can change the difficulty in the game menu under Game Settings -> Difficulty. You also may change this while game when it turns too boring or too hard.

Comment: How did the changing of difficultly affect your achievements/trophies/etc in the end?

Comment: I didn´t put attention at this point, but i will check it later